Claude Intellij Integration
I am trying to integrate ClaudeMind on intellij, i have a Anthropic account with free tier and have generated the API key as recommended on the site, i have installed the plugin and entered the key which it accepts gracefully, however when i am trying to use Claude for any work on Intellij it responds with the following error message

Response failure, please try again. Error message: {"type":"error","error":{"type":"invalid_request_error","message":"Your credit balance is too low to access the Anthropic API. Please go to Plans & Billing to upgrade or purchase credits."}}

I am doing this for the first time and hence i am pretty sure that there isnt any issue with limits of quotas here.
Anyone has any recommendations?
